# How to verify install-tl-windows.exe binary

Tags: installing, windows

How does one verify the integrity of the install-tl-windows.exe TeXLive installation binary?  Is there a PGP/GPG signature, or some listing of hashes for the various binaries?  I don't like to run installers that I have not validated.

Comment: Just download from the credible source (official list of tl mirror sites)

Answer (score 3):

You normally download the installer from CTAN (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet). There you find three related files: `install-tl-windows.exe`, `install-tl-windows.exe.sha512` and `install-tl-windows.exe.sha512.asc`. The first is the installer itself, the second file contains the SHA512 hash of the first file and the third is a PGP signature of the second file. (So it's a signature of the file containing the hash, not of the installer directly.)

The corresponding [PGP public key](https://tug.org/texlive/files/texlive.asc) can be found on the [TeX Live site](https://tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate your help!   -Dan